# How to Export DataGridView to PDFth/Excel/Word for Easy Print?

Tags: c#, printing, datagridview

Guys what I have is a simple gridview in C# windows form application which is being populated by a database. Now I want to add a functionality to print it. I googled and tried different methods but none have worked so far (Some printed blank pages, while other misprinted the data).

This is the code which gave me the best result (it doesn't print all the records which can be viewed by scroll)..

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        PrintDialog printDialog = new PrintDialog();
        printDialog.Document = printDocument1;
        printDialog.UseEXDialog = true;
        if (DialogResult.OK == printDialog.ShowDialog())
        {
            printDocument1.DocumentName = "Test Page Print";
            printDocument1.Print();
        }
    }

    private void printDocument1_PrintPage(object sender, System.Drawing.Printing.PrintPageEventArgs e)
    {
        Bitmap bm = new Bitmap(this.dgRecords.Width, this.dgRecords.Height);
        this.dgRecords.DrawToBitmap(bm, new Rectangle(0, 0, this.dgRecords.Width, this.dgRecords.Height));
        e.Graphics.DrawImage(bm, 0, 0);
    }
```

Now I thought maybe the work-around was that if I could export the datagridview to any other file such as excel sheet, pdf or word document and then I could print it from that file. I have tried to export it to excel but haven't been successful. It just prints header and one row.

This is the code for excel-export

```
    private void ToCsV(DataGridView dGV, string filename)
    {
        string stOutput = "";
        string sHeaders = "";
        for (int j = 0; j < dGV.Columns.Count; j++)
            sHeaders = sHeaders.ToString() + Convert.ToString(dGV.Columns[j].HeaderText) + "\t";
        stOutput += sHeaders + "\r\n";
        for (int i = 0; i < dGV.RowCount - 1; i++)
        {
            string stLine = "";
            for (int j = 0; j < dGV.Rows[i].Cells.Count; j++)
                stLine = stLine.ToString() + Convert.ToString(dGV.Rows[i].Cells[j].Value) + "\t";
            stOutput += stLine + "\r\n";
        }
        Encoding utf16 = Encoding.GetEncoding(1254);
        byte[] output = utf16.GetBytes(stOutput);
        FileStream fs = new FileStream(filename, FileMode.Create);
        BinaryWriter bw = new BinaryWriter(fs);
        bw.Write(output, 0, output.Length); //write the encoded file
        bw.Flush();
        bw.Close();
        fs.Close();
    }  

    private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SaveFileDialog sfd = new SaveFileDialog();
        sfd.Filter = "Excel Documents (*.xls)|*.xls";
        sfd.FileName = "export.xls";
        if (sfd.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            ToCsV(dgRecords, sfd.FileName);  
        }  
    }
```

Could some one tell me what am I doing wrong? I just need to print the gridview - doesn't matter if it is directly by the print button or by export it to some other file.

EDIT :

```
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application ExcelApp =
                 new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel._Workbook ExcelBook;
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel._Worksheet ExcelSheet;

        int i = 0;
        int j = 0;

        //create object of excel
        ExcelBook = (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel._Workbook)ExcelApp.Workbooks.Add(1);
        ExcelSheet = (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel._Worksheet)ExcelBook.ActiveSheet;
        //export header
        for (i = 1; i <= this.dataGridView1.Columns.Count; i++)
        {
            ExcelSheet.Cells[1, i] = this.dataGridView1.Columns[i - 1].HeaderText;
        }

        //export data
        for (i = 1; i <= this.dataGridView1.RowCount; i++)
        {
            for (j = 1; j <= dataGridView1.Columns.Count; j++)
            {
                ExcelSheet.Cells[i + 1, j] = dataGridView1.Rows[i - 1].Cells[j - 1].Value;
            }
        }

        ExcelApp.Visible = true;

        //set font Khmer OS System to data range
            Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range myRange = ExcelSheet.get_Range(
                ExcelSheet.Cells[1, 1],
                ExcelSheet.Cells[this.dataGridView1.RowCount + 1,
                    this.dataGridView1.Columns.Count]);

        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Font x = myRange.Font;
        x.Name = "Arial";
        x.Size = 10;

        //set bold font to column header
        myRange = ExcelSheet.get_Range(ExcelSheet.Cells[1, 1],
                                 ExcelSheet.Cells[1, this.dataGridView1.Columns.Count]);
        x = myRange.Font;
        x.Bold = true;
        //autofit all columns
        myRange.EntireColumn.AutoFit();

        //
        ExcelSheet = null;
        ExcelBook = null;
        ExcelApp = null;
```

Okay so I tried this method of export to excel and it works fine, it opens up a excel sheet with all the data from my datagrid but after opening up the excel sheet, it generates RuntimeBinder Exception

```
        'object' does not contain a definition for 'get_Range'
```

at this line

```
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range myRange = ExcelSheet.get_Range(
                ExcelSheet.Cells[1, 1],
                ExcelSheet.Cells[this.dataGridView1.RowCount + 1,
                    this.dataGridView1.Columns.Count]);
```

What seems to be the problem? I can't figure it out...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`DataGridView` doesn't support direct print functionality. You have started in right direction in using the `PrintDocument` and handling the `PrintPage` event.

In the print page event handler, you have to print the `DataGridView` row by row. See this [article](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/28046/Printing-of-DataGridView) for more information.

Sample Code:

Have class level variable int `rowIndex=0;`

In the `PrintPage event handler`,

```
int rowTop=e.MarginBounds.Top;
bool needMorePages=false;
while (rowIndex<= dataGridView1.Rows.Count - 1)
{
    DataGridViewRow row = dataGridView1.Rows[rowIndex];
    if(rowTop + row.Height >= e.MarginBounds.Top + e.MarginBounds.Height)
    {
        needMorePages = true;
        break;
    }
    foreach (DataGridViewCell Cell in row.Cells)
    {
        //draw cell content
    }
    rowTop += row.Height;
    rowIndex++;
}
e.HasMorePages = needMorePages;
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. My VS can't seem to resolve GridRow symbol. Why is that?

Comment: @user3331470 - I have corrected the code. The code is an example. You have still draw the borders, header texts etc... see the article I have linked. It provides you a complete working example